# Android Dynamic Tabs

Tags: android

I am creating a dynamic tab feature for my Android application. When the user is on the ast Tab and swipes right, I want it to go to the first tab.

How would one implement this?

1. Detect the gesture.
2. Set Tab to the first Tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for circular loop to handle Infinite ViewPager

https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager